# Django:Can not load app config (Apps aren't loaded yet)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, tastypie

I am following a [tutorial](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2016/04/30/a-practical-guide-for-building-restful-api-with-django-tastypie/) using python 3.5 and Django 1.10 to making a backend, but there is a problem I can not solve. This error also occurs in the author's code downloading from github.
I have been spending a day in this question, thank you for your time.

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/Users/Charles/djangop1/urban_tastes/services/apps.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 105, in __new__
app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 237, in get_containing_app_config
self.check_apps_ready()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

### app.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from tastypie.models import create_api_key

class ServicesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'services'
    def ready(self):
       # This line dispatches signal to Tastypie to create APIKey
       signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)

<__init__.py>
default_app_config = 'services.apps.ServiceConfig'

<settings.py>
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tastypie',
    'services'
]
```

Answer (score 4):

> File "/Users/Charles/djangop1/urban_tastes/services/apps.py", line 2, in  
>   from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Your problem is importing the `User` model directly in `app.py`.

See the docs on [*Referencing the User model*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

You either need to use the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting or `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()`.

> Generally speaking, you should reference the user model with the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting in code that is executed at import time. get_user_model() only works once Django has imported all models.

In your case `User` is being used in the `ready()` handler so `get_user_model` would work.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Gibson, but I am a beginner and I can not figure it out, could you  please type out the specific code?

Comment: The best thing for a beginner is to read the documentation. Click the link I provided and have a look. The exact code you need is all there.

Comment: It did not work although I edited apps.py : signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL), and added AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'services.User' in setting.py,

Answer (score -1):

As I got it, the error happens when you try to run server. Fortunately, Django has an awesome command `./manage.py validate`. This command will show you what really happened.

Comment: `validate` command is deprecated since django 1.7, use `./manage.py check` instead. as shown in [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#validate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#validate)

Comment: if you are try to run `validate` command, you will get same error. Also it is not an answer for this question. So please make it as a comment.